# How can I determine the accessibility of a MemberInfo instance?

Tags: .net, reflection

I know the BindingFlags are used to fetch public and non-public members from a Type.

But is there a way to determine if a MemberInfo instance (or derived like PropertyInfo, MethodInfo) is public or not (after it was returned from one of the methods on Type)?

Answer (score 9):

`PropertyInfo`, `MethodBase` etc each have an `Attributes` property which has this information - but there's nothing in `MemberInfo`, because each kind of member has its own kind of attributes enum. Hideous as it is, I think you *may* need to treat each subclass of `MemberInfo` separately :( You can probably switch on [`MemberInfo.MemberType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.membertype.aspx) and then cast, which will be *slightly* nicer than lots of `as`/test-for-null  branches, but it's still not ideal :(

```
if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
{
    var property = (PropertyInfo) member;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I also see that PropertyInfo does not have PropertyAttribues to indicate its accessability. So I need to get the Accessor methods and go with those. Thanx for your explaination.

Comment: @obiwanjacobi: Presumably that's because you can have different accessibility for the get and set.

Comment: How can you get Propertyinfo from MemberType?  There is no cast.

Comment: @DanielWilliams: I see you've worked out what the answer meant.... I've edited the sample you provided to improve the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ie:

```
var isPublic = memberInfo.MemberType switch
{
  MemberTypes.Field => ((FieldInfo)memberInfo).IsPublic,
  MemberTypes.Property => ((PropertyInfo)memberInfo).GetAccessors().Any(MethodInfo => MethodInfo.IsPublic),
  _ => false
};
```

For properties this return true if there is *any* public accessor which I think is what you're after